# EntityFramework GroupBy Entity Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have a base entity A, and derived entities: AA, AB, AC, AD

```
context.A.GroupBy(x => x.GetType()).Select(x => new { type=x.GetType(), count = x.Count() });
```

Of course I get error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Type GetType()'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How can i group derived entities by type?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing exactly the same issue.

Comment: did either of you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If types are predefined, you could use [Enumerable.OfType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)

```
var acs = context.A.OfType<AC>().Count();
```

Comment: Thanks but i do it with GroupBy(). Types are generic.

Comment: What you mean under Types being generic?

Comment: I have a function and functions first parameter is type of base entity. In this question, base entity is A, and function returns AA, AB, AC... and record counts. But when base entity is X, function must return XY, XZ, XX and record counts. have explained?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hydrate your entities to memory before calling the GroupBy - this way the x.GetType() call will be handled by LINQ to Objects and not LINQ to Entities. Try doing this:

```
context.A.ToList().GroupBy(x => x.GetType()).Select(x => new { type=x.Key, count = x.Count() });
```

I changed it so you call x.Key and not x.GetType() in your select, otherwise you will get the type of the grouping which will be something like IGrouping<...>

Comment: Yes, that is works but i maybe have million records. Some way do it in LINQ to Entities?

Comment: You can't, as it says.. LINQ to Entities does not support .GetType(), how would you translate GetType() to sql? SQL does not support inheritence, it's a feature implemented in code by entitiy-framework.

Comment: can you filter by discriminant?